# Highlight div corners for cropping tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a cropping tool where I need to highlight corners of a div with strong black like so: 
 
(Any kind of highlight on the corner will be fine, the one shown in the image is overdoing it). 
[image]
 
 Such a highlight would indicate diagonal cropping as opposed to linear cropping on the edges. How can I accomplish this using CSS or javascript. (Borders can be easily highlighted, but corners?)
 
Thanks!

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I dont know how to code for corners of a div, coding for div border is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Then what you need to do is code all the parts you do know how to do, so that the only part left is the bit that you don't know how to do. Then google for how to do something with div-corners... and try things until you find something that looks like it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is to create four child div with the background you want (the corners) and position them relative to the crop div in the four corners.

If you want full custom box, you can think like if your box was a 9 case 
[grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJsvM.gif). 
Now you have your first div, which contain three div, that the lines and into these three div you have three other, now you have to customize the box with an image editor and put it as the background. And size your crop box correctly.